# conan.io: clone package repository in consumer's working directory

Tags: git, conan

I have a source-only package with the following directory structure:

```
src (directory containing source files)
conanfile.py
```

The pkg's recipe `conanfile.py` looks like this: (copy everything when doing the pack)

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools

class PkgConan(ConanFile):
   name = "pkg"
   version = "0.0.1"
   license = "License of pkg here"
   url = "URL of pkg here"
   description = "Description of pkg here"
   settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
   generators = "cmake"

def package(self):
    self.copy("*")

def package_info(self):
    self.cpp_info.libs = ["pkg"]
```

My package is consumed by an integration project which copies the pkg's sources in its working directory.
The consumer's recipe `conanfile.txt` looks like this:

```
[requires]
   pkg/0.0.1@user/test

[imports]
   ., * -> ./packages/pkg
```

When installing the dependencies in the integration project, the pkg's sources are copied in the consumer's working directory as expected.
Consumer's working directory:

```
packages
   pkg
      src (directory containing pkg's source files)
      conanfile.py
conanfile.txt
```

**Here's my usecase**: The `pkg` is versioned with [git](https://git-scm.com/) and uploaded to GitHub. I want to have the entire git repository of `pkg` in the consumer's working directory instead of only pkg's sources.
Expected consumer's working directory:

```
packages
   pkg (repository cloned from GitHub)
      .git
      src 
      conanfile.py
conanfile.txt
```

**???** Is it possible with [conan](https://conan.io/) to clone the package repository in the consumer's working directory and also checkout the correct version (e.g. checkout commit/tag corresponding to the required version) instead of using the sources coming from `[imports]   ., * -> ./packages/pkg` **???** E.g. I found a bug in `pkg`, I want to correct it in the consumer's context and provide the bugfix back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, at least with the approach you are following and current conan features. There could be other issues, not related to conan, for example, the ".git" folder might not be relocatable to other system.

Then, the approach is relatively fragile if at some point you have settings, options, requirements of different versions, as you could end with different packages, for the same recipe. Remember that 1 recipe => N "binaries". Even if you are not building from sources, this relation is maintained. And of course, trying to use conan for binaries, which is the main use case, will break this.

I think you might be interested in the new SCM feature: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/package_repo.html#capturing-the-remote-and-commit-from-git-scm-experimental. With this repo the flow would be:

- Add `scm`, with `auto` field to your recipes. The commit will be captured when the package is created.
- Work with your package, lets say `MyPkg/0.1@user/channel`, which has a dependency to `MyDep/0.2@user/channel`.
- If at some point you want to edit `MyDep/0.2@user/channel`, checks its SCM detail with: `conan get MyDep/0.2@user/channel`
- `git clone` with those details.
- Use the local workflow to edit and build that package locally: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/developing_packages/package_dev_flow.html
- When you want to check if `MyPkg/0.1@user/channel` works properly with latest changes, of `MyDep`, make sure that you run the last step `conan export-pkg` over `MyDep`, so the latest changes are in the conan local cache.

This flow is what the conan **Workspaces** aims to further automate: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/developing_packages/workspaces.html. The idea could be to have a `conan workspace open MyDep/0.1@user/channel` to automate the above steps, and bring a dependency from the local cache directly to your current user workspace. Note that this is not implemented yet.

Comment: `scm` is what I need to get the URL and version, but I have to `git clone` the package manually in another location than the consumer's working directory... and this is what I want to avoid. I will check the `conan workspaces`. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, I understand the use case, but still, packaging a .git folder, fetching it from a binary conan repository, installing it in the cache, to finally import it in user space sounds a bit too forced and it might have other issues. I really think the way to go is to obtaint the commit from the SCM info, then do a proper clone & checkout in user space. As said, not a feature yet, but your feedback in the github repo might help the team to prioritize.